# Half-bridge converter gate-source voltage, Miller effect

Tags: power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I am trying to understand the parasitic effects in MOSFETs, especially in the half-bridge configuration.

As shown in the figure there is a negative voltage glitch before the MOSFET turns on. My opinion about this phenomenon: a current is flowing through Cds of M2. That's why a negative voltage is generated on Cgs.

Can anybody give information about the reason for the negative voltage of Vgs?

Dead-Time 4us, V(n003)-Vgs of M2, V(N001,HB2)-Vgs of M1

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Can anybody give information about the reason for the negative voltage in Vgs?` it comes from the M1's turn-off. Scope both of the gate-source signals, increase the dead-time for better readability and to prevent shoot-through, and you'll see that the spikes are sync'd to the other MOSFET's turn-off.

Comment: Hi, I attached Vgs of M1 as well, Mr.Rohat. Yes, increasing dV/dt will cause a shoot-through on leg. To decrease dV/dt, increasing gate resistor is a solution. But it will also increase voltage drop on the gate signal. There is a trade-off.

Comment: Place a capacitor (a few tens to a few hundreds of pF) across the M1's (high-side switch) drain-source and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is changed. Maybe, I have a problem with the simulation parameter. ı attached the with .step param..

Comment: The capacitance value should be selected by taking the reverse transfer and output capacitances into account. Because, by adding a cap the division ratio of the divider formed by low-side MOSFET's reverse transfer capacitance and high-side MOSFET's output capacitance will change. This has a significant effect on the induced negative gate-source voltage. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/2gT2Wfd.png) is a result from my half-bridge LLC converter simulation (Blue: Low-side NMOS Vgs, Green: High-side NMOS Vgs). For your MOSFET Crss=500p and Coss=680p. So maybe you should try with 1n or higher.

Comment: And it's related to the dead-time between the gate pulses. So try to increase the dead time just a little and see if it helps. Note that you can't get rid of the spikes completely. But you can decrease it to an acceptable level.

Comment: Please use node labels and not invisible-to-the-viewer node numbers. It's not miller effect imho.

Comment: Mr. Rohat, when I increase dead time to 4us, it is now visible. You mean, the is high voltage change in Coss of M1 and this will cause a current and it will flow through Cgd of M1. Rigt?

Comment: As you can see, as you change the capacitance the spike goes above -2V. And as I stated above, you can't completely get rid of the spike but decrease it to an acceptable level. Somewhere around -1V is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, but just to understand this phenomenon, the current will flow oppposite way through off resistor of M1 and that why there is a negate voltage on Vgs. Is it logical for you? Because there is huge voltage in Coss of M1 and current will find a path through Cdg of M2 and turn off resistor of M2.

Comment: Gate drive output is zero and gate voltage is negative (both w.r.t. MOSFET source). The diode won't allow any current as it'll be reverse biased. But a small current flow from gate driver output to the gate through the "on" resistor (R1 or R2). If the peak of the spike is 1V then a current of ~50mA will flow for a few (or few tens of) nanoseconds (Like shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/8VwEJeI.png), 80mA/div, 400ns/div). Do you see any problem here?

Comment: Yes, it can be self-turn-on and cause shoot-through on the leg.

Comment: I think when someone doesn't "play the game" and accept answers and/or make upvotes on answers, they might be eventually recognized by other users and, not given the help they perhaps think they deserve. Just a polite observation that is aimed to try and help you get answers.

Comment: I am not familiar features of comments. All of the comments were very useful for me.

Comment: Then show me an example of a self turn-on cused by a gate-source voltage between -1V and 0V. By adding a capacitance across M1 you slowed down the switch node (in other words, decreased dV/dt) and therefore decreased the chance of possible self turn-on.

Comment: I will share with you Mr. Rohat.